# Within the same row, adding data validation and formula in different cells when data is entered on another cel

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is more a practical, cosmetic and elegant improvement to a google sheet.

Data Validation in column C
Instead of having data validation already available in column C, first n rows, I would like a script to make data validation available in the row where data its being entered so I dont see the dropdown triangle all the way down on the rows. Ex. When data is entered in A2, data validation ((List from a range, =variables!$J$2:$J$1000) option appears automatically in C2

Formula in column H
Instead of having a formula already available in the first n rows, I would like a script to make enter the formula in the row where data its being entered. When data is entered in A2, formula "=IF(J2="x",2,1)" is automatically entered H2

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are looking for something that can do this:

[image]

I don't mean the stuff to the left just the drop down boxes

Comment: Somebody helped me solve my question a few minutes ago, but I would love to see how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/multiple-dependent-drop-downs